# Preciso selecionar o ultimo valor do Dataframe para calcular o valor da próxima linha da mesma coluna

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Preciso selecionar o ultimo valor da coluna "Mínimo da Temporada" para calcular o valor de "mint", nome que dei a variável da mesma coluna, atualmente minha linha de códigos está assim:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#DATABASE
data = {'Jogos':[1, 2, 3, 4], 
    'Placar':[12, 24, 10, 24],
    'Mínimo da Temporada':[12, 12, 10, 10],
    'Máximo da Temporada':[12, 24, 24, 24],
    'Quebra recorde mín':[0, 0, 1, 1],
    'Quebra recorde max':[0, 1, 1, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

j = input("Número de Jogos:")
p = input("Qual foi o placar?:")

mint = 0
if int(p) < :
    mint = p


new_row = {'Jogos':j, 'Placar': p, 'Mínimo da Temporada': mint, 'Máximo da Temporada': maxt, 'Quebra recorde mín': qrmin, 'Quebra recorde max': qrmax,}

df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Perdão pela possível linguagem incorreta, estou aprendendo a programar ainda.

Comment: Bem vindo, Gabriel. Primeiramente. remova a imagem do post e cole o código para que possamos copiar, testar, editar, etc; Depois que colar o código na pergunta, selecione-o e use o atalho Ctrl + K para formatá-lo corretamente.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, ainda não sei usar direito esse site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para selecionar o ultimo elemento você pode utilizar o iloc:

```py
df['Mínimo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]
```

Saída:

```
10
```

---

**Edit**

Para adicionar o valor na variável mint:

```py
mint = df['Mínimo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]
print(mint)
10
```

Comment: E para definir o valor da variável como esse mesmo valor, o ultimo desta coluna do Dataframe, como eu faria? `Mint = df['Mínimo da Temporada]`?

Comment: Fala Gabriel, bom dia! Atualizei a resposta com essa sua nova dúvida. Abraço!